# Redux App not working if Redux DevTools Extension is not installed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app, redux-devtools-extension

I have followed the guide here: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html (Section: Redux DevTools)

The store is configured in the following manner:

```
// @flow

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { createReducer } from './reducer';
import { epic } from './epic';

const initialState = {};

const configureStore = () => {
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(epic);
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const enhancers = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));
  const store = createStore(createReducer(), initialState, enhancers);
  return store;
};

export { configureStore };
```

However, my React Application (bootstrapped with CRA) will not work if I don't have the Redux Devtools Extension installed.

Can someone please tell me what it is that I am doing incorrectly?

Error log on missing extension: https://pastebin.com/qzcbXCYQ

EDIT: I am an idiot. The store was defined in two files, and I was not changing the one where I was importing it from. Cleaned up the duplicates, and it is working as expected.

Comment: yes, you must add redux dev tool. Because with installing dev tool you can not add that to your store.

Comment: Eh no, it should default to using `compose` from `redux` when the extension is not present.

Comment: When you don't have the dev tools installed, what errors do you get? A little more info about your project (build setup etc.) could also be helpful.

Comment: @noppa It's vanilla CRA (not ejected), and error log is here: https://pastebin.com/qzcbXCYQ

Answer (score 8):

To make things easier, you can use the `redux-devtools-extension` package from npm.

To install it run:

```
npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension
```

and to use like so:

```
// @flow

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { createReducer } from './reducer';
import { epic } from './epic';

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';


const initialState = {};

const configureStore = () => {
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(epic);
  const enhancers = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));
  const store = createStore(createReducer(), initialState, composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware),
      // other store enhancers if any
));
  return store;
};

export { configureStore };
```

Comment: and if one has the extension installed in Chrome already and does not wish to NPM it?

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar issue. I just needed to tweak a single line. I went from this:

```
const composeEnhancers = !__PROD__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : compose
```

To this:

```
const composeEnhancers = !__PROD__ ? (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose) : compose
```

In my case I have the `__PROD__` variable available, but tweak that to suit your situation. Logic remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually comes with browsers dont having redux-devtool (May occur in chrome incognito chrome also)

I think you should check with your composeEnhancers

```
  const composeEnhancers =
      typeof window === 'object' &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?   
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
    }) : compose;
```

reference : https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually comes with browsers dont having redux-devtool (May occur in chrome incognito chrome also)

compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**||compose)

it's Shoud be worked

or try another
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import blogReducer from "./Reducer/blogReducer";

const store = createStore(
blogReducer,
compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window._*REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION* && window._*REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION*() || compose));

export default store

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).