# How can I view network requests (for debugging) in React Native on Windows?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, redux, react-devtools

I found a lot of answers on this topic
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190781/redux-app-not-working-if-redux-devtools-extension-is-not-installed) but they were all about Mac Os, I would like to view my network requests in React Native to help me debug **Windows**. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger
Right-click and choose "Enable ..." -> Select "Network" tab. Remember to enable debug JS on your simulator

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw4mb.png)

Comment: how i know, it's lib only for mac os. maybe it's work for mac os, but how i can do this for windows?